# Loading custom file based on a dependant file that is also dependant on another file

Tags: jquery

i will start at the beginning.

I have a website that is running the Master Slider Pro wordpress plugin and the iLightBox plugin. I am running a custom script in a custom.js file in wordpress child theme.

From what i understand, the custom.js file requires the ilightbox file to be loaded which in turn requires jQuery to be loaded.

My current code looks like the below:

```
/* Ensure jquery loads before iLightBox */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

            function add_my_script() {
                wp_register_script( 'ilightbox_script', get_theme_root_uri() . '/Avada/includes/class-avada-scripts.php', array('jquery'), true );
                wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery', 'ilightbox_script'), true );
                wp_enqueue_script('ilightbox_script');
                wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');
            }
```

At present i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).iLightBox is not a function
```

To narrate, what i believe i am doing is:

1. register my themes script that includes the iLightBox function, this will register once jQuery has been loaded.
2. register my custom.js file which will register once jQuery and iLightBox has been loaded.
3. Load the ilightbox script.
4. Load the custom.js script.

My page can be seen below:
http://www.complete-models.com/gallery/cars-trucks/124-dodge-monaco/

Am i going wrong here ?

Comment: You actually don't need `wp_enqueue_script('ilightbox_script');`. The system will load dependencies automatically. This looks like a Javascript problem-- that is, it looks like `iLightBox` isn't defined. Are you sure that is the correct function name?

Comment: I am certain iLightBox is a function.
I can get the whole thing working with the following code, however it i visit another page then hit back the error appears. It looks to me like sometimes jQuery loads before the custom.js and the ilightbox script (correctly) and other times loads after it (incorrectly) which throws the error.

`function custom_scripts() {
 wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery') , false, true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 99 );`

Comment: @s_ha_dum any ideas

Comment: I expect that the problem is in your JavaScript. Does the script wait for the page to load?

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved. nothing wrong with the script i posted. turns out i was calling the wrong file in the first wp_register_script()